# Cannot configure context/ get kubectl working on node01 at Katacoda playground

Tags: linux, kubernetes, katacoda

`$ kubectl config get-contexts` returns nothing on node01 in the cluster. I went as far as to set the password on the master node and then ran `$ sudo scp -i master@172.17.0.133:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config`, but got permission denied. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed in order to make it work:

- `sudo su` on Node01 and change the password to one of your liking
- `sudo scp /root/admin.conf  root@Node01IP:/root/` (you can use Node01 instead of IP)

on Node01:

- `sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf`
- `export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf`

Run `kubectl get nodes` or `kubectl config get-contexts` or any kubectl command to verify.